# CiviCRM admin screens don't display icons/special chars

Tags: theme, ui

See screen snippet below. The question marks and other graphical items normally displayed throughout the CiviCRM UI are showing as squares with the unicode. This is a dev instance, copied (codebase and databases) from a production instance using the instructions [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switch-servers/). The symbols show correctly in the production instance. What did I mess up?!?

CiviCRM 5.23.1 and Drupal 7.69.

[image]

Comment: If you look in your browser dev console are there any errors? Also if you copied over civicrm.settings.php check inside there for anything that seems wrong.

Comment: Humble apologies. Feel free to post a response along the lines of "Children, remember to triple-check your civicrm.settings.php" and I'll up-vote it. I could've sworn I had adjusted it but, alas, it still pointed to the production base url. Symbols now display correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments the problem was civicrm.settings.php still had old settings.